# Probability that two sets are disjoint? the same?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

Suppose two sets of $2$ elements, $\{X_1, X_2\}$ and $\{Y_1, Y_2\}$ are uniformly and independently chosen from the set of two element subsets of the integers $\{1, 2, \dots, r\}$, where $r \geq 1$.

1. What is the probability that the two sets are disjoint?
2. What is the probability that the two sets are the same?
3. What is the expected size of the intersection of the two sets?

I've tried to attempt these questions, but I'm completely wrong. It would be nice if you guys can help me out. Thanks

Comment: "but I'm completely wrong" Show what you have tried, even if this is "completely wrong".

Answer (score 3):

There are $\binom{r}{2}^2$ ways of choosing two sets of two integers each from the integers $\{1, 2, \dotsc, r\}$. If we want them to be disjoint, then after choosing the first set, we should choose the second set from the remaining integers, which are $r - 2$ in number. Thus the number of pairs of disjoint sets is $\binom{r}{2}\binom{r-2}{2}$. The probability is
$$
\begin{align}
P &= \frac{\binom{r}{2}\binom{r-2}{2}}{\binom{r}{2}^2} \\
&= \frac{\binom{r-2}{2}}{\binom{r}{2}} \\
&= \frac{(r-2)!}{2!(r-4)!} \cdot \frac{2!(r-2)!}{r!} \\
&= \frac{(r-2)(r-3)}{r(r-1)}
\end{align}
$$

The number of ways of choosing two sets that are the same is simply $\binom{r}{2}$, so the probability is
$$
\begin{align}
P &= \frac{\binom{r}{2}}{\binom{r}{2}^2} \\
&= \frac{1}{\binom{r}{2}} \\
&= \frac{2!(r-2)!}{r!} \\
&= \frac{2}{r(r-1)}
\end{align}
$$

$\frac{(r-2)(r-3)}{r(r-1)}$ of the time, the sets will be disjoint, so the intersection has size 0. $\frac{2}{r(r-1)}$ of the time, the sets will be the same, so the intersection has size 2. Since the intersection can only be of size 0, 1, or 2, the probability that the intersection has size 1 is $1 - \frac{(r-2)(r-3)}{r(r-1)} - \frac{2}{r(r-1)} = \frac{4(r-2)}{r(r-1)}$. So,
$$
\begin{align}
E &= \frac{(r-2)(r-3)}{r(r-1)} \cdot 0 + \frac{4(r-2)}{r(r-1)} \cdot 1 + \frac{2}{r(r-1)} \cdot 2 \\
&= \frac{4}{r}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to define the random variable $$D:=\text{ the number of common elements in the two sets}$$ with values in $\{0,1,2\}$. With this notation, you want to find:

1. $P(D=0)$
2. $P(D=2)$
3. $\Bbb E[D]=0P(D=0)+1P(D=1)+2P(D=2)=P(D=1)+2P(D=2)$

where of course $P(D=1)=1-P(D=0)-P(D=2)$. Actually question 3. is an indication that you should indeed work this way, i.e. by introducing $D$. One way to proceed is to note that $D$ has the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) with parameters $N=r, K=2, n=2$ where the $K=2$ successes correspond to the two numbers $X_1,X_2$ and the $n=2$ draws to the numbers $Y_1,Y_2$.

Alternatively (but with more effort then) you can calculate things directly $$P(D=0)=\frac{\dbinom{2}{0}\dbinom{r-2}{2}}{\dbinom{r}{2}}=\frac{(r-2)(r-3)}{r(r-1)}$$ which is justified as follows: Knowing the values $\{X_1,X_2\}$ you want to draw $2$ numbers $Y_1,Y_2$ from the remaining $r-2$ values and $0$ values from these $2$. This gives the numerator. The denominator counts all possible ways to draw the $2$ numbers $Y_1,Y_2$ from the $r$ numbers. Similarly $$P(D=2)=\frac{\dbinom{2}{2}\dbinom{r-2}{0}}{\dbinom{r}{2}}=\frac{2}{r(r-1)}$$ and $P(D=1), \Bbb E[D]$ follow. You can also verify $P(D=1)$ directly by: $$P(D=1)=\frac{\dbinom{2}{1}\dbinom{r-2}{1}}{\dbinom{r}{2}}=\frac{4(r-2)}{r(r-1)}$$

Actually, the above work for $r\ge 3$. For smaller values of $r=1$ or $r=2$ it is better to do a separate computation.